# jquery 1.7.1 conflicting with jquery.min

Tags: jquery

Hi I have two scripts a news ticker and ratings the news ticker users jquery.min and its own js to query the database. the ratings script requires jquery.1.7.1 I have tried to use the noConflict solution but it does not work one of the scripts fail to load.

I have tried using a different version jquery.1.3.1 which shows the ratings script and partialy loads the news but the news only scrolls a few lines and stops.

Newsticker and ratings code

```
     {literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#js-news').ticker({
            speed: 0.10,
            pauseOnItems: 2000,
            controls: false,
            fadeInSpeed: 600,
            titleText: 'Our Latest News'
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                //start plugin
                jQuery(".stars").rating({                                       
                    php : 'ratings/admin/manager.php',  
                    skin : 'ratings/skins/skin.png',        
                    debug : true                
                });                 
            });

        </script>   
{/literal}
```

I have also tried a newer version but this didn't work either any suggestions

thanks

M

Comment: You should only use the newer version.

Comment: It's a really bad idea to have two different versions at the same time. It's more likely easier to find scripts that work with the same version of jQuery.